# plasma task manager icons

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma, taskmanager

Problem in Kubuntu 20.04:

I try to pin an application to the taskmanager. I have put the desktop file in /usr/share/applications. I have put the icon in /usr/share/pixmaps (as .xmp and also .png)

Adding there to desktop shows correct icon and link works great. However, pinning the application to the taskmanager shows no icon (look at rightmost application missing icon) :
[missing icon in taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wTXZ.png)

I have absolutely no idea where I should place icons to get that working